# Using numpy present value function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to compute the present value using numpy's pv function in pandas dataframe.
I also have 2 lists, one includes period [6,18,24] and other one includes pmt 
values [100,200,300].
Present value should be computed for each value in pmt list to each value in period list.

lets say in below table column values represents period and row represents pmt

[image: Click to see the image]

I am trying to compute the data values using a single line of code without writing multiple lines How can I do that?

Currently I hard coded the period as follows.

```
PRESENT_VALUE6 = np.pv(pmt=-PMT_REMAINING_PERIOD,rate=(INTEREST_RATE/12),nper=6,fv=0,when=0)
PRESENT_VALUE18 = np.pv(pmt=-PMT_REMAINING_PERIOD,rate=(INTEREST_RATE/12),nper=18,fv=0,when=0)
PRESENT_VALUE30 = np.pv(pmt=-PMT_REMAINING_PERIOD,rate=(INTEREST_RATE/12),nper=30,fv=0,when=0)
```

I want the python to iterate the nper from the list, currently when I do that it produces the following not the expected result

[image: Click to see the image]

Expected result is

[image: Click to see the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what interest rate you used in your example, I set it to 10% below:

```
INTEREST_RATE = 0.1

# Build a Cartesian product between PMT and Period
pmt = [100, 200, 300]
period = [6, 18, 24]
df = pd.DataFrame(product(pmt, period), columns=['PMT', 'Period'])

# Calculate the PV
df['PV'] = np.pv(INTEREST_RATE / 12, nper=df['Period'], pmt=-df['PMT'])

# Final pivot
df.pivot(index='PMT', columns='Period')
```

Result:

```
                 PV                          
Period           6            18           24
PMT                                          
100      582.881717  1665.082618  2167.085483
200     1165.763434  3330.165236  4334.170967
300     1748.645151  4995.247853  6501.256450
```